# How to generate a media graph with multiple lines on the y-axis for the months of the year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know how do I generate a graph of multiple Y lines for the months of the year.
I have a data.frame with 3 temperature monitoring stations over 3 years for different dates from 2000 to 2002.

I would like to calculate the monthly average temperature on the X axis and on the Y axis to place the three stations.

how to make this?

following this example
[image]

my dataframe

```
  sample_station <-c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C')
Date <-c('01/01/2000','08/08/2000','16/03/2001','22/09/2001','01/06/2002','05/01/2002','26/01/2002','16/02/2002','09/03/2002','30/03/2002','20/04/2002','04/01/2000','11/08/2000','19/03/2001','25/09/2001','04/06/2002','08/01/2002','29/01/2002','19/02/2002','12/03/2002','13/09/2001','08/01/2000','15/08/2000','23/03/2001','29/09/2001','08/06/2002','12/01/2002','02/02/2002','23/02/2002','16/03/2002','06/04/2002')
Temp <-c(17,20,24,19,17,19,23,26,19,19,21,15,23,18,22,22,23,18,19,26,21,22,23,27,19,19,21,23,24,25,26)

df<-data.frame(sample_station,Date,Temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Date, Temp, color = sample_station) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = '6 months', date_labels = '%b %Y')
```

Comment: @wesleysc352 Thanks...My answer should work for your data. Can you try that?